# ThreeJS apply properties from one camera to another camera

Tags: three.js

In my webapp I'm using ThreeJS scenes in different modals/popups/dialogs with different width/height ratios.

Furthermore, I want to use multiple user defined camera settings (rotation, position, lookAt etc.) among these different scenes.

Therefore, I save the camera object via `camera.toJSON()` when the user clicks a capture camera settings button.

(Before I did this, I saved just the object `camera`, but unfortunately these objects are quite big and slow down the performance while multiple camera objects get stored. Nevertheless, this approach worked, since I was able to copy all the desired values between the saved camera object and the currently used camera [e.g. `current_camera.position.x=saved_camera.position.x` and so on])

In every scene I want now to use the saved properties I tried the following:

```
let m = new THREE.Matrix4();
m.fromArray(saved_camera.object.matrix);
current_camera.applyMatrix(m)
current_camera.updateMatrix();
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work.

---

"normal" `camera` object
[image]
`camera.toJSON()` object
[image]

Comment: Why not `camera.copy( savedCamera )`?

Comment: @WestLangley This produces a bunch of errors, since `savedCamera` is not a type of `THREE.PerspectiveCamera`, due to the applying of `.toJSON()`

Comment: Don't use `.toJSON()`. Just create new camera instances called `savedCamera`, and then to save: `savedCamera.copy( camera );`. To restore: `camera.copy( savedCamera )`.

Comment: @WestLangley Copying to a temporary camera, and restoring the camera after an action, this method worked perfectly. I had overlooked such a simple method!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're comfortable using matrices, then you can turn off the matrix auto-update that three.js does during the render process, and keep the world matrix up-to-date yourself. (This includes any time you change the camera's orientation, so keep that in mind if you're using some form of mouse interaction to control the camera angle.)

First, turn off automatic matrix updating for your camera by setting the `autoUpdateMatrix` property to `false`. You can still use the convenience properties (`position`, `rotation`, `scale`), but you'll have to manually update the world matrix by calling `camera.updateMatrixWorld(true);`.

Finally, when you're ready to restore a particular camera orientation, simply *copy* the matrix values using the `matrixWorld`'s `copy` method.

```js
var origin = new THREE.Vector3();
var theCamera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, 1, 1, 1000);
theCamera.autoUpdateMatrix = false; // turn off auto-update

theCamera.position.set(10, 10, 10);
theCamera.lookAt(origin);
theCamera.updateMatrixWorld(true); // manually update the matrix!

console.log("Camera original matrix: ", theCamera.matrixWorld.elements.toString());

var saveMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();

saveMatrix.copy(theCamera.matrixWorld);
// saveMatrix now contains the current value of theCamera.matrixWorld

theCamera.position.set(50, -50, 75);
theCamera.lookAt(origin);
theCamera.updateMatrixWorld(true); // manually update the matrix!

console.log("Camera moved matrix: ", theCamera.matrixWorld.elements.toString());
// theCamera.matrixWorld now holds a value that's different from saveMatrix.

theCamera.matrixWorld.copy(saveMatrix);
// Don't upate the matrix, because you just SET it.

console.log("Camera moved matrix: ", theCamera.matrixWorld.elements.toString());
// theCamera.matrixWorld once again contains the saved value.
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
```

**Edit to address OrbitControls:**

It looks like `OrbitControls` uses the convenience properties, rather than gathering the information from the matrix. As such, when you restore a camera position, you'll also need to restore those properties. This is easily done by using `decompose` on the matrix, and copying the resulting values into the appropriate properties:

```
var d = new THREE.Vector3(),
    q = new THREE.Quaternion(),
    s = new THREE.Vector3();
camera.matrixWorld.decompose( d, q, s );
camera.position.copy( d );
camera.quaternion.copy( q );
camera.scale.copy( s );
```

Comment: Does `theCamera.autoUpdateMatrix = false;` have an impact on OrbitControl? Can I still use OrbitControl with this approach?

Comment: @d4rty I've updated my answer with more information addressing your comment.